# How to show a color caption on the Vega Stacked Bar Chart?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I am using this chart: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/stacked-bar-chart/

[image]

I want to show a color note for the chart below.

[image]

But I can't find a solution to apply this type of chart. Do you have any solution for this type of chart?

Comment: Do you mean a legend? Have you tried Vega-Lite as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just add Legend in.

```
"legends": [
{
  "title": "% of Obese Adults",
  "orient": "right",
  "type": "symbol",
  "fill": "color",
  "format": ".1%",
  "clipHeight": 16
}
```

],